Some layers of my designed deep learning model are initialized in the model class but are not used in the forward process,which cause different result
Some layers of my designed deep learning model are initialized in the model class but are not used in the forward process. I found that when the code of these layers are remained, the performance is different from the result when the code of these layers are deleted. Does this phenomenon caused by initialization of model? An example is as follows:
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwgs):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = ...
        self.layer2 = ...
        self.layer3 = ...

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        return out

When the self.layer3 is remained, the performance is different from when the self.layer3 is deleted. However, the self.layer3 does not participate in the train and test, why can it influence the performance?
I try to delete the code of the model initialization. the result is still the same as the above mentioned.

Models are initialised with random weights. Thus each creation of the class creates a new model with it's own weights and etc. Regarding layer3 - it will be dropped from the model graph during the inference. Does this answer your question?

Thanks for your answer. If layer 3 is dropped from the model graph during the inference, why it will influence the model performance? I set a random seed of 42. It is like when I delete layer 3, the RMSE loss is 0.5; When I remain layer 3, the RMSE loss is 0.45. Both of them are run with the same setting. This result makes me confused. Does the existence of layer 3 influence the initialization of the other part?

If you can take weights from second model and input them in the first model and model1 will have same RMSE without layer 3 then layer 3 doesn't influence anything except initial randomisation. And I'm quite sure that this statement is valid. Most probably you in the first model you stopped training too early or didn't tune Learner parameters.

Basically I would rephrase the question to how you are training the model and why it can't reach the more optimal RMSE value.

Yes, you are right. I suppose that the existence of layer 3 influences the initialization. I am just curious that, I have already set the same random seed, why still this can influence the initialization and lead to a better performance.  The training hyper-parameters of the two models are the same, and no early stop is deployed. So maybe this is the reason that the model without layer 3 can not reach a lower RMSE. The hyper-parameter may not be the best for its initialization parameter. Again thanks for your patient answer.  I will optimize the setting of the model with layer 3.
